# running utility when user logs out

Tags: gnome-terminal, automation, logout

is there any way by which we can run utility on logging out.
There is a server which has account of many users. Now If I login to that server I can put utilities in .bashrc, but I want to kill processes automatically ( which were started by me ) when I logged out. So is there any way?
I can only access that server using terminal ( command line utility i.e. no gui access ).

Comment: When you log out, any processes you started as yourself during that session will get killed automatically as you want. There is nothing you have to do to explicitly kill them manually.

Comment: no they don't, specially background processes and process started with nohup.

Comment: Can this thread help you? http://superuser.com/questions/65460/create-a-logoff-script-task-for-linux

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure. Make a script that:

1. invokes the user's shell, which allows them to do whatever they want as usual; and then
2. runs whatever program you want to run once the shell is finished (the user is "logging out").

Set that script to the the user's login shell. That should do what you want.